# How to prove this is a partial order??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $R$ be the partial order on $\mathbb{N}$ (set of all natural integers) defined by:
$$n \leq m \iff m = (2^k)\cdot n \;\text{ for some }k \in\mathbb{Z},\, k \geq0.$$

I know the basic idea on how to prove a relation is a partial order.  I just need to prove $R$ is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

This is what I have so far on the question posted above.  Probably very far off, so spare the flaming.

a) For any $n \in R, (n, n) \in R$
    (i.e. $n = (2^k)\cdot n$ | $n$ will always be less than or equal to itself).
    Therefore $R$ is reflexive.

b) Let $(n,m) \in R$ and $(m,n) \in R$.  $n ≤ m$ and $m ≤ n$ by definition of $R$.
    Therefore $n = m$ property of $R$.  Therefore $R$ is anti-symmetric.

c) Let $(n,m) ∈ R$ and $(m,O) ∈ R$.
    $m = (2^k)\cdot n$ and $O = (2^l)\cdot m$ for $k, l ∈ R$     definition of $R$.
    $\implies n = m/(2^k)$ and $m = O/(2^l)$
    $\implies n = (O/(2^l))/(2^k)$
    $\implies n\cdot(2^k) = (O/2^l)$
    $\implies(O/2^l) = (2^k)\cdot n$
    Therefore $(n,O) ∈ R$ by definition of $R$.
    Therefore $R$ is transitive.

Since $R$ is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive, it is a partial order.

My proof of $R$ being anti-symmetric is probably the most shaky, even though they are all pretty shaky.  Can anyone help me prove $R$ is a partial order or help improve my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reflection

At your solution, you write $n\in R$. This can't be. $R$ is a relation and contains pairs (of integers), not integers.

Also saying that $n$ is always less or equal to itself is not sufficient, because "less or equal" is defined on the existence of a positive number for which this equation holds. So, you have to show that there is a $k$ (actually is 0), for which $n=2^k\cdot n=2^0\cdot n=n$. And so, for all $n\in N$, you'll have $(n,n)\in R$.

#### Anti-symmetry

Say $(n,m),(m,n)\in R$. This means by definition that there are $k_1,k_2$ such, that $$m=2^{k_1}\cdot n$$
and
$$n=2^{k_2}\cdot m$$

By substitution you get
$$m=2^{k_1}\cdot 2^{k_2}\cdot m$$

Since $k_1,k_2>0$, you get $k_1=k_2=0$. So, $m=n$

#### Transitivity

Zero is a specific number, but transitivity of the relation must hold on all the domain.
Say you have pairs $(n,m)$ and $(m,s)\in R$. This means that for some $k_1$,

$s=2^{k_1}\cdot m$

and for some $k_2$,

$m=2^{k_2}\cdot n$

By substitution you get

$s=2^{k_1}\cdot 2^{k_2}\cdot n = 2^{(k_1+k_2)}\cdot n$

The last equation shows that $(n,s)\in R$.

Comment: Thank you.  How would I draw a Hesse Diagram for the elements {1,2,...12} using this partial order, btw??  Is it as simple as 1 being on the bottom going all the way up to 12??

Comment: You must find all triples $(n,m,k)$ for $n,m=1,\ldots,12$ that satisfy that equation. For each such triple that you find, you'll connect $n$ with $m$.

Comment: Stupid question, what is a triple??

Comment: It's not a term or something. I meant that if you find three numbers n,m and k such that $m=2^k\cdot n$, then you'll connect n and m on your diagram. But you have to find all three-number combinations that satisfy the equation.

Comment: To clarify, the first three three-number combination that comes to mind are (1,1,0), (1,2,1) and (6,12,1).  I don't know how this helps me create a hasse diagram??

Comment: For example, (6,12,1) means that $(6,12)\in R$ and in the hasse diagram you have to draw a line from 6 to 12.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, your $R$ is defined as $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\mid \exists k\in\mathbb{Z}\,\,(x=2^ky)\}$. For proving it is:

Reflexive: Try to prove $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}\,(x,x)\in R$. Start by assuming $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Then show that $(x,x)\in R$. Since you made no other assumptions on $x$, you have proved $\forall x\in\mathbb{N} (x,x)\in R$.

Antiymmetric: You need to prove  $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}\,(\,(x,y)\in R\land(y,x)\in R\,\,\implies\,\, x=y\,)$. So, start by letting $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ and then suppose $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$. Then prove $x=y$.

Transitive: You need to prove $\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}\,(\,(x,y)\in R\land(y,z)\in R\,\,\implies\,\,(x,z)\in R\,)$. Start by assuming $x$, $y$ and $z$ to be arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{N}$ and suppose $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$. Then prove $x=z$.